# Automate arrangement of multiple displays in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display

I  work in an open space office type with external monitors at every single work space. I don't have a set work space, so everytime I connect to a new external monitor screen I get the default open of two screens next to each other. I exclusively work in a mode where the two screens are on top of each other in the arrangement window.

Is there any way that I can automate the arrangement in Windows 10, e.g. if I connect a new monitor to run a quick batch command to set the arrangement?

I know that it is only about 3 clicks if done regularly but it gets annoying if it occurs every single day.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with PowerShell. First create a Powershell script called "MoveScreens.ps1" and copy and paste the following code in:

```
Function Set-ScreenPosition { 
param ( 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
  Position = 0)] 
[int] 
$x, 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
  Position = 1)] 
[int] 
$y 
) 
$pinvokeCode = @"
using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
namespace Mover
{

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct DEVMODE
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string dmDeviceName;

        public short dmSpecVersion;
        public short dmDriverVersion;
        public short dmSize;
        public short dmDriverExtra;
        public int dmFields;
        public int dmPositionX;
        public int dmPositionY;
        public int dmDisplayOrientation;
        public int dmDisplayFixedOutput;
        public short dmColor;
        public short dmDuplex;
        public short dmYResolution;
        public short dmTTOption;
        public short dmCollate;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string dmFormName;

        public short dmLogPixels;
        public short dmBitsPerPel;
        public int dmPelsWidth;
        public int dmPelsHeight;
        public int dmDisplayFlags;
        public int dmDisplayFrequency;
        public int dmICMMethod;
        public int dmICMIntent;
        public int dmMediaType;
        public int dmDitherType;
        public int dmReserved1;
        public int dmReserved2;
        public int dmPanningWidth;
        public int dmPanningHeight;
    };
    public class NativeMethods
    {
        // PInvoke declaration for EnumDisplaySettings Win32 API
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(string lpszDeviceName, int iModeNum, ref DEVMODE lpDevMode);

        // PInvoke declaration for ChangeDisplaySettings Win32 API
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DEVMODE lpDevMode, int dwFlags);


        // constants
        public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1;
        public const int CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x01;
        public const int CDS_TEST = 0x02;
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL = 0;
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_RESTART = 1;
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_FAILED = -1;



        public static DEVMODE CreateDevmode()
        {
            DEVMODE dm = new DEVMODE();
            dm.dmDeviceName = new String(new char[32]);
            dm.dmFormName = new String(new char[32]);
            dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dm);
            return dm;
        }
    }



  public class PrimaryScreenPosition
  { 
    public static string ChangePosition(int x, int y) 
    { 
        DEVMODE dm = NativeMethods.CreateDevmode(); 
        if (0 != NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(@"\\.\DISPLAY1", NativeMethods.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm)) 
        { 
            dm.dmPositionX = x;
            dm.dmPositionY = y;


            int iRet = NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, NativeMethods.CDS_TEST); 
            if (iRet == NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_FAILED) 
            { 
                return "Unable To Process Your Request. Sorry For This Inconvenience."; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                iRet = NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, 0); 
                switch (iRet) 
                { 
                    case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL: 
                    { 
                        return "Success"; 
                    } 
                    case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_RESTART: 
                    { 
                        return "You Need To Reboot For The Change To Happen.\n If You Feel Any Problem After Rebooting Your Machine\nThen Try To Change Resolution In Safe Mode."; 
                    } 
                    default: 
                    { 
                        return "Failed To Change The Position"; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return "Failed To Change The Position."; 
        } 
    } 

  } 
} 
"@ 
Add-Type $pinvokeCode -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
[Mover.PrimaryScreenPosition]::ChangePosition($x,$y) 
}
```

Then create another script to run the above like so (the numbers are the width and height respectively of your second screen, and obviously you'll need to update the path to wherever you put the first script!):

```
.\C:\Temp\MoveScreeens.ps1
Set-ScreenPosition 1920 1080
```

Then you just need to run the second script and it should stack the screens for you with the primary being on the bottom.

**Caveat:** This may not work depending on the Script Execution settings on the machine, if you run into that you need to run the script with the appropriate setting enabled:

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\MoveScreens_Stack.ps1
```

**Another Caveat:** This script assumes that the monitors are arranged horizontally with the left display being #1. If they are in a different arrangement (e.g. *already* in a vertical arrangement) then weirdness will likely ensue!

Comment: Your code won't compile. You need to change `[Resolution.PrmaryScreenPosition]` to `[Mover.PrmaryScreenPosition]` and `CreateDevmode` is not accessible from the other class unless you specify `NativeMethods.CreateDevmode` and even changing all these stuff the code gives the same error. I think that `dmPosition` is not declared correclty.